# Benefit of combining a clustered columnstore index and a nonclustered columnstore index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, data-warehouse

I ran into a question about **indexing a large fact table in a data warehouse** asking to implement **two** indexes in order to optimize performance and the answer suggested to create:

- a clustered **columnstore** index (CCI)
- and a nonclustered **columnstore** index (NCCI) on part of the columns

As a CCI includes all the table's columns, I would have thought that there would be no point in combining two columnstore indexes (one clustered and one nonclustered) and rather go for :

- a clustered **columnstore** index (CCI)
- and a nonclustered **rowstore** index on part of the columns

(see [microsoft documentation on columnstore index design guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-ver15))

**What would be the benefit, if there is any, of combining two columnstore indexes (one clustered and one non clustered) on a large fact table** in a SQL Server database / data warehouse **?**

The question that triggered my question can be found [on this page](https://www.examtopics.com/exams/microsoft/70-767/view/18/), question 70.
I don't know if I am missing something or if their solution is inaccurate.

If anyone could help me out, it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As a CCI includes all the table's columns, I would have thought that there would be no point in combining two columnstore indexes

Indeed it's not even allowed.  If you try you'll get

```
Msg 35339, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Multiple columnstore indexes are not supported.
```

The question

[image]

Since Index1 contans all the data and is optimized for aggregations, it should be a clustered columnstore index.

And so he correct answer for the Index2 is a a unique nonclustered index with included columns, where any non-key columns are the included ones.